# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'price')

Tags: javascript

when i try to run this code, it gaves me this error.
the problem is in the totalPrice function
return prev += (product.price * basket.amount)
how can i fixed this? I think it should run but it doesn't

```
let basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('basket')) || []
const products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'MacBook Pro 2021',
        price: 40000
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Keychron K6',
        price: 100
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'NuPhy Halo65',
        price: 140
    }
]

function saveToStorage() { ...

}

function addBasket(productID) { ...

}

function removeBasket(productID) { ...
}

function totalPrice() {
    return basket.reduce((prev, basket) => {
        const product = products.find(p => p.id === basket.productID)
        return prev += (product.price * basket.amount)
    }, 0)
}


console.log(
    totalPrice()
    )
```

Comment: mind if you could make a sandbox where you can show full code. You can use stackoverflow snippet . This will make easier to understand what exactly is the problem.

Comment: @DecPK Why an external sandbox instead of stack snippet?

Comment: @Barmar I meant for full code doesn't matter where user wants. Appreciate your comment.

Comment: You'll get this error if `products.find()` can't find a match. Either figure out why the basket contains nonexistent product IDs, or use `if (product)` to verify that it found something.

Comment: While I could not reproduce my self, you could try renaming the arugment in reduce from `basket` to something like `item` to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the issue is the line of code:

`const product = products.find(p => p.id === basket.productID)`

The [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method will return an `undefined` if the array you are searching through does not have an element which fits the condition you provided.

You should handle the `undefined` which may be returned by the find function.

The below code may work for you. I haven't tested it, but you should get the idea of what to do. You need to make sure that the data you need *exists* before you use it for something.

```
        
        const product = products.find(p => p.id === basket.productID)
        
        if (product && product?.price) {
          return prev += (product.price * basket.amount)
        }
        
        return prev += 0;
```